# Пунктуация в предложении!

Tags: пунктуация

При выдаче бланков в г. Санкт-Петербурге(,) сотрудник должен позвонить в центральных офис по номеру: 888 88 88, в других городах (?) сотрудник обращается к партнерам компании.

Comment: Может быть, вы все-таки увидите очепятку в заголовке своего вопроса, и исправите ее?

Answer (score 1):

При выдаче бланков в г. Санкт-Петербурге сотрудник должен позвонить в центральных офис по номеру 888 88 88, в других городах ему следует обратиться к партнерам компании.